# adding ## to maven 3 artifact name for tomcat 7 parallel deployment

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-deploy-plugin

I have read quite a few answers on this forum, so hopefully I am asking something.
Recently we moved to Tomcat 7 and usual procedure is to pick up a war file from Nexus repository, stick it in tomcat webapps dir and start the server and use it.
But due to war file artifact name in Nexus being my-app-war-1.0.war context path in tomcat is not what is expected. I know that this can be configured by context.xml, but I was wondering if there is a way to add ## to artifact name that is deployed in Nexus.

I tried changing @{project.build.finalName} but it only changes artifact name in target directory, maven deploy plugin still uses artifactId, which is 'my-app-war'. So artifact in Nexus ends up being 'my-app-war-1.0.war' As artifactId in maven has a quite strict structure and ## is not allowed there I was wondering what would be the right way of adding ## to artifact name, as we are very likely to consider to use parallel deployment, so I am looking for ways to enable this functionality.

I guess I could deploy two versions of the same war file to Nexus, one being named slightly different(with ##), but then it`s easier to just rename it and save some space. I wonder was there any plan how would the ## would be added to application name, when Parallel naming feature was implemented in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<classifier>` configuration of `maven-war-plugin`. This way your `war` will be installed to the repository with the name `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-my-app-war.war`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>##my-app-war</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: It is a way to add ## to artifact name, but ideally I would like to add ## before ${project.version}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Nexus returning the following error if you include in maven version `##`.

```
Illegal character in fragment at index 103
```

You can enter in  `<path>` by deploying to Apache7 the characters `##` for the paralell deployment as folowing:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>remote</id>
    <phase>deploy</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>deploy</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <mode>war</mode>
      <path>/${project.artifactId}-##${project.version}</path>
      <url>http://tomcat7.../manager/text</url>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <update>true</update>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```